# Binary Search for a char in a string - Java

Tags: java, string, search, binary, char

I am trying to do my assignment. I think that I am really close to solving it, but I can't do it.. I've been trying to do it for last several hours.

What I am trying to do: I have a string and a char. I am trying to implement the binary search to look for a char, but it doesn't return the value that I want. Well it is correct, but I want this code to return 5 instead of 4.

This is my code, can You help me to solve it? There is no sort method, because I didn't want the code in here to be super long, but please assume that sorting method sorts correctly. If you'd like to see the sorting method then I am able to upload it for you.

I would appreciate any kind of help, because I've spent way to much time for it.. :/.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String s = "abcdefg";
         char c = 'e';
      System.out.println(findRecursiveD(s, c));

     }

     public static int binarySearch(char[] a, char c, int start, int end) {

      int mid = (start + end) / 2;
      if(a[mid] == c) 
          return mid;
      else if (a[mid] < c)
          return binarySearch(a, c, mid+1, end);

      else
       return binarySearch(a, c, start, mid);
     }

     public static int findRecursiveD(String s, char c) {
      int start = 0;
      String S = s + c;
      char[] b = S.toCharArray();
      int end = b.length;
      sort(b, 0, end);
      String A = new String(b);
      System.out.println(A);
      return binarySearch(b, c, start, end);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Use [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28char[],%20int,%20int,%20char%29).

Comment: I would use it, but I can't, we need to create such method by ourselves. I did it with a loop, but we need to use recursive method :/

Comment: What is the purpose of `String S = s + c;`? Why do you want to add searched character to string in which you are looking for this character? Are you trying to make sure that string will contain at least once character you are looking for? Can't you just return `-1` if character is not present in string?

Comment: We use cloudcoder to check if the assigment is correct and for input "abcdefg" it says that 5 for char 'e' is correct answer. So I thought that I am gonna concat String with a char so there are two e's in the char array, but it still returns 4.. I have just no idea how to make it return 5.

Comment: I'm guessing that cloudcoder assumes indexing from `1`, not from `0` which makes this result `5` not `4`. Consider using `if (a[mid] == c) return mid+1;` as result. Also consider adding cases where `start > end` which will represent situation on which character wasn't found in string (return `-1` then).

Comment: BTW, in `findRecursiveD` method `end` shouldn't be set to `b.length`, but to `b.length - 1` (If you would look for `x` which would not be present in string, and it would be greater than other characters, you would end up with checking `array[length]` which will throw OutOfBounds exception, because max index is equal to `length - 1` because array elements are indexed from 0, not 1).

Comment: I tried adding 1 to mid (return mid+1), but that doesn't solve my problem, because cloudcoder checks four inputs and one of them is just "a". If I added 1 to mid it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can't change the input for the problem just to get the right output. Anyone would fail you for that.

Comment: You probably didn't understand. Cloudcouder checks several inputs itself. Even if I had main method in my code cloudcoder would ignore it and use his main method. I hope that You can understand me. English is not my first language.

Comment: I understood what you wrote. You added an 'e' to the input so you would get the right answer. You fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually correct, but your concept of what the correct index is may be off. Arrays in Java are [zero-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), which means the first element of the array actually is `0`, not `1`. So in the character array you provided, `e` is the fifth element, but that means that to access it, you would do `s[4]` to reference it.

If you really want to return `5` instead of `4`, you should just add one to your answer.

Comment: after concating a String with a char there are two e's in my char array (abcdeefg) I want this code to look for a place of second e not the first one. I kinda want this code to return "how many letters are there before 'e' ".

Comment: A binary search will never guarantee that you will get the second.  It will randomly fine one or the other.  IF you always want the second, you will have to add a linear search to find the 'last' character of that value.

Answer (score 0):

USe this:

```
System.out.println(findRecursiveD(s, c) + 1);
```

You need to add one, because the 5th position in the string is position 4.  The first position int eh string is numbered 0.   4 is the correct answer if you want the number of the position.  But if you want to count starting with 1, then you need to add one.

Also, you need to terminate searching when start == end.  You will run into bad problems is start+1 is greater than end, so you should test for, and avoid this situation.  When start == end, then after to verify that the character at position mid (== start == end) is not c, then check for this condition and return something special, like -1, or throw an exception.

```
public static int binarySearch(char[] a, char c, int start, int end) {

  int mid = (start + end) / 2;
  if(a[mid] == c) {
      //now search for the 'last' character of that value
      while (mid+1<a.length && a[mid+1]==c) {
          mid++;
      }
      return mid;
  }
  else if (start==end) {
      //if no character of that value found
      return -1;
  }
  else if (a[mid] < c) {
      return binarySearch(a, c, mid+1, end);
  }
  else {
      return binarySearch(a, c, start, mid);
  }
}
```

And remove the statement that adds a character into the string being searched.  I don't see why that overhead of adding in a value helps, and it seems like a bad coding practice to learn anyway to modify the search data before you search it.

Comment: That is a good idea, but not what I need. We use cloudcoder for the assingments and my code doesn't have to include main method, it's already implemented by a teacher.

Comment: It still returns 4, not 5. :(

Comment: then return mid+1 from the method.  If I look at that string, the index of the 'e' is 4.  If the assignment is to return the index plus 1, then add a one.

Comment: There is also input "a" that cloudcoder checks and it doesn't work then.. That silly assignments :/