# Recursive binary search -- Java

Tags: java, binary-search

I've searched extensively online but all solutions I've found use two parameters to keep track of the size of the area being used. This would be easy if I was allowed to do that, but I'm not. As you can see below, the code lacks a stop value, because I have no idea how to retain the original information.

This is the code on Wikipedia, you can see they use imin and imax for tracker variables: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Recursive

My (very incorrect) code is below. The `mid` variable doesn't mean anything, because I don't know how to set low and high correctly if I'm not allowed to have any extra arguments in the function.

```
public static int findRecursiveB( String s, char c)
{
    int low = 0;             
    int high = s.length()-1;
    int mid = (low+high)/2; 

    if (s.charAt(mid) < c) {
        return findRecursiveB(s.substring(low, mid), c);
    }
    else if (s.charAt(mid) >= c) {
        return findRecursiveB(s.substring(mid+1, high), c);
    }
    else return mid;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate or a similar question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308699/binary-search-for-a-char-in-a-string-java

Comment: are you allowed to create a helper method?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to have them ? Can't you have a function call to a private method in which you have them, and form your recursive logic that way ?

Comment: The environment (created by my CS professor) I'm working on is unfortunately pretty rigid. I only have this function to work on.

Comment: If you pass a substring to the recursive call, the result will be the position *within the substring*, so you will have to add the offset of the substring to the position. Further, setting `high`to `s.length()-1` instead of `length()` means you are cutting off a char at the end on each recursion. And you should think about what happens, if the search `char` is not contained at all, i.e. the substring becomes empty…

Answer (score 0):

One crucial point here is what does the original `String s` contain?  For this to work, it has to be a sorted String, meaning that the characters in the String must be in order.  Specifically, it looks like you've written code that expects `s` to be sorted in reverse order.  Otherwise, unless I'm totally missing something, your code does exactly what it is supposed to: no need to pass extra params because you are passing in the substring on each recursive call.

Otherwise, good job.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify: s is in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: For some reason though, my tests don't seem to work. For example recursiveB("hgfedcba", 'b') yields an "index out of bounds" error. These are the errors: http://i.imgur.com/SeRXTO6.png

Comment: Change the greater than or equal to sign to just a greater than sign, as the other answer suggests.